# MySQL, Select, Merge tables

Tags: mysql, merge

I have a little problem that I can´t solve. It´s really simple, but I just can´t figure it out and have search some time but not found any good answers.

I have two tables:

```
Transaction
t_nr (Primary)   a_nr     quantity
 1                1          10
 2                2          10 
Customer
c_nr (PRIMARY)  name        city
 1              Mario       Tokyo
 2              Luigi       Beijing
```

And want to insert values from the two above into another table with one query looking 
Account
 a_nr (primary)   c_nr

Problem is that when just making a regular select-from-statement it returns:

```
a_nr     c_nr
 1        1
 1        2
 2        1
 2        2
```

i.e. not just merges them together in the account table.

```
a_nr     c_nr
 1        1
 2        2
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What is your `SELECT`?

Comment: Instead of selecting *, type in only the fields you want. a_nr, c_nr, desired_column1, desired_column2, desired_column3, etc...

Comment: what I have tried is:

Comment: insert into account (a_nr,c_nr)  select transaction.a_nr, customer.c_nr  from transaction, customer

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills!

Answer (score 1):

Does a_nr correlate to c_nr (are they equal)?

If so,

```
insert into account (a_nr,c_nr)
SELECT transaction.a_nr, customer.c_nr from transaction, customer
WHERE transaction.a_nr = customer.c_nr
```

Although this seems completely pointless to only insert two values that are the same.

What is the desired output of Account?